# Why "it" is used for two words connected with or?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

could you please tell me why we use "it" and "that" as singular pronouns in this sentence? Do we always do the same in Eglish or we can you use plural pronouns instead too?
:

> Blockquote
>   Skin too light or too dark? Creams can handle **that**. Gummy smile or biggish nose? Surgery can remake **it**.

Comment: Because "A or B" is singular? "This match will decide whether Smith or Jones **is** better."

Comment: You're right; plural agreement would be expected here, at least in the second case. But 'Surgery can remake those' sounds less punchy – in fact, verging on unidiomatic. 'That' for 'those [related] situations' is probably quite acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not parallel constructions, and that may be confusing you.

> Skin too light or too dark? Creams can handle that.

Here, *that* refers to the (singular) situation.

> Gummy smile or biggish nose? Surgery can remake it.

Here, *it* refers to the (singular) situation.

Comment: Would you allow 'A rip in your jacket or a headache? Aspirin can help.'? 'It' _can't_ just refer to the second disjunct.

Comment: Thanks, I edited for clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'it' isn't intended refer to both 'smile' and 'nose' in a rather naughty (but punchier) construction (as OP hints).

Answer (score 0):

In the first part Blackquote skin is singular so the pronoun 'that' is used. In the second Gummy smile and biggish nose are two things but they are connected by the conjunction "or so the pronoun" it "is used For example, It is a wooden chair or an iron chair.Isn't it?

Comment: @Hot Licks' I have answered and deleted the previous answer submitted on behalf ov